# Can I invoke a program using another program in console only in C++

Tags: c++

Can someone guide me as to how would I be able to invoke a program from another program in C++.

Ideally this would be somewhere along the lines of

`Program01.exe (Program02.exe arg1 arg2) arg3 arg4`

basically I would like to give the program with it's own arguments as an individual argument to the second program who would probably read the main()'s return value and use that as an argument.

Can this be done using only console only - no windows libraries - as I would eventually like to port this project to other platforms.

Comment: Are you looking for `system()`? It takes a string and executes it, as if you typed it on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the C Standard Library function system(). This part of the C Standard Library is also part of C++ and should be available for any standards compliant implementation.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

From the arguments given to your program you would prepare a string that is the command to be run. What this function will return is up to the implementation but it is likely to behave as your describe - return the value returned by main().

Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab5b6c3066a42851

For POSIX compliant operating systems another option is the exec family of functions.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html

These functions are operating system specific but along with other functions defined by POSIX they allow finer grain control such as manipulating stdin and stdout of programs.

Comment: Awesome, this solved my problem. Could this be called on a CUDA kernel as well? I doubt it though, since these are CPU calls I assume.

Comment: And you'd be right. That aside, there's likely a better way to achieve your ends than system() calls from multiple threads.